# Difference between socks5 and socks4 proxy?

Tags: proxy

I know what is socks proxy and how does it differ from http proxy. I want to know what is the main difference between socks5 and socks4 proxy.

Comment: How does [the Wikipedia article on SOCKS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS) not address your concerns? Show your research.

Comment: I studied it but it still did not convinced me. Was searching for ultimate answer

Comment: @PrabeshThapa: what do you consider the "ultimate answer" ? What features you expect from this answer which the Wikipedia article does not have?

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich I was looking for more convincing answer, to the point not more not less

Comment: @PrabeshThapa: regarding SOCKS the most convincing are the standards which are referenced by wikipedia. But feel free to study these standards to get the most convincing answer.

Comment: I guess you are right. Thank you  @Steffen Ullrich

Answer (score 10):

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS#Protocol):

> The SOCKS5 protocol is defined in RFC 1928. It is an extension of the SOCKS4 protocol; it offers **more choices for authentication** and adds **support for IPv6 and UDP**, the latter of which can be used for **DNS lookups**.

And compared to plain SOCKS4 it also has the [main feature from SOCKS4a](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS#SOCKS4a):

> SOCKS4a extends the SOCKS4 protocol to **allow a client to specify a destination domain name rather than an IP address**; this is useful when the client itself cannot resolve the destination host's domain name to an IP address.